# Euclidean Division Theorem program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write a code to count quotient and remainder according to Euclidean division Theorem.

```
a,b=input().split()
a=int(a)
b=int(b)

if(a<0 and b>0):
    q=int(a/b)-1
    r=a-(b*q)
    print(q,end=" ")
    print(r)

elif(a>0 and b<0):
    q=int(a/b)
    r=a-(b*q)
    print(q,end=" ")
    print(r)

elif(a>0 and b>0):
    q=int(a/b)
    r=a-(b*q)
    print(q,end=" ")
    print(r)

elif(a<0 and b<0):
    q=int(a/b)-1
    r=a-(b*q)
    print(q,end=" ")
    print(r)
```

Is here any bug to count quotient and remainder according to Euclidean  division Theorem..??Acctually this is uri online judge's 1837 no problem.I write this code and submit but showing 40%wrong answer.program description:https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1837

Comment: Try this:https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/hcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong answers are due to the fact that your current implementation does not ensure that the calculated `r` will be a positive number when `a,b < 0`. In fact, if you check the link provided you will see that the theorem defines `0 ≤ r < |b|`

Testing your current algorithm with input values `a = -7` and `b = -3` you will get `q = 1` and `r = -4`. But as said we need `r ≥ 0`

Try the following code again with input values `a = -7` and `b = -3`. This time you will get `q = 3` and `r = 2`, which satisfies as well the `a = b × q + r` equation: `-7 = -3 x 3 + 2`

Finally - just to avoid misunderstandings - I added a condition to control and explicitly cover those inputs where b = 0, another situation not accepted by the Euclidean Division Theorem

```
def euclidean_division(a, b):

    if(a < 0 and b > 0):
        q = int(a/b) - 1
        r = a - (b*q)

    elif(a > 0 and b < 0):
        q = int(a/b)
        r = a - (b*q)

    elif(a > 0 and b > 0):
        q = int(a/b)
        r = a - (b*q)

    elif(a < 0 and b < 0):
        q = int((a+b)/b)
        r = a - (b*q)

    return q, r  

def main():
    print("Please insert two integer values separated by a space")
    print("NOTE: the second integer is NOT allowed to be equal to zero")
    first_input, second_input = input().split()
    first_int=int(first_input)
    second_int=int(second_input)

    if(second_int != 0):
        first_output, second_output = euclidean_division(first_int, second_int)
        print("q = " + str(first_output) + " r = " + str(second_output))
    else:
        print("Second integer must be other than 0")
        print("Try again\n")
        main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

NOTE: this example proves also the importance of having `r ≥ 0` to guarantee the uniqueness of the solution